# Google Analytics default code handle http and https?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics

Well I have a domain that run at http but when the user go to payment page it run at https, then i need to track both http and https.

I need to change something in this default track code or not?

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-76202182-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change url to protocol relative URL.

So change from https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js to //www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-76202182-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Comment: is this necessary? Seems like https should work from an http page.

Comment: Its not necessory at all, but if we want to track both http as well as https then only

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is wrong. The standard code will work fine on both https and http pages.

The changed url in the answer does not even refer to the tracking call, this is the url from which the tracking library is loaded. It used to be that ssl incurred additional load on the server, so Google used to have relative urls to switch to ssl only when necessary, but that's all in the past, so now they have the ssl url right there in the default code.

Use the standard code and you will be fine. You can even force ssl independently from your page's protocol by [using the force ssl option](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#forceSSL),  this will not affect page tracking.

Comment: I concur, and this should be the accepted answer. Supplemental info from Webmasters: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/51698/google-analytics-http-vs-https